# How to get 'file creation time' in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, porting

I need to find out at what time and date a file has been created using C++ in Linux.

Answer (score 10):

[How do I get the date a file was last modified?](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/lastmod.html).

```
struct stat attrib;                 //1. create a file attribute structure
stat("file_name", &attrib);         //2. get the attributes of afile.txt
clock = gmtime(&(attrib.st_mtime)); //3. Get the last modified time and
                                    // put it into the time structure
```

[4.8 File Times Update](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html):

> In Linux: three distinct timestamps associated with a file:
>
> - time of last access of contents (`atime`),
> - time of last modification of contents (`mtime`),
> - and time of last modification of the inode (metadata, `ctime`).

So, no, you **cannot** find file creation time. [(reference)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time). Some useful Links related to you question:

- [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)
- [Get file created/creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time)
- A good article, ["file creation times"](http://lwn.net/Articles/397442/).

Comment: Now implemented via statx   see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man2/statx.2.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems no easy way to get exactly the creation time but you can get time of the last modification, last access and last status  change.

You need to use the [structure stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html), defined in sys/stat.h. [Here is the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) on how to obtain and use this structure.