# How to get the list of files created during a specific period of time in a directory?

Tags: c++, linux, file

I need to get the list of files that have been created within a specific period of time in a directory, e.g files created after 19:14 and before 23:11. Each directory contains files belonging to a specific date (24 hours). Should I include the creation time of each file in its name? (like `prefix-hh-mm-ss-ms.txt`). These files are meant to be copied from another place to the directory, so I am afraid copying may modify the [creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698250/69537) of file and I should not rely on it. Any advice showing me the best way to achieve what I want to do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Copying should not "modify" the creation time; since the destination file was actually only created at copying time, isn't it only logical that the creation time of the copied file is the time when the copying occured?

The file creation time is however not really available under linux anyway (see the question you linked yourself [How to get 'file creation time' in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697941/how-to-get-file-creation-time-in-linux-using-c/13698250#13698250), or https://superuser.com/questions/437663/whats-an-elegant-way-to-copy-the-creation-and-modification-dates-of-a-file-to-a).

So you'll have to encode that in some other way anyway. Encoding it in the filename as you suggest sounds like a reasonable way!